# guild.channels.filter is not a function discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make a user presence but I am getting an error:

```
guild.channels.filter is not a function
```

My code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('847071265100791849');

const categoryChannels = guild.channels.filter(
  (channel) => channel.type === '886241068855734273'
);

categoryChannels.forEach((channel) => {
  const statuss = channel.children.size - 2;
  client.user.setPresence({
    status: 'online',
    activities: [{ name: `${statuss} Open Tickets ✉️`, type: 'WATCHING' }],
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`guild.channels` returns a `GuildChannelManager` so it doesn't have a `filter` method. You can [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) all channels that returns a collection, and then you can use `filter` on that:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('847071265100791849');
const channels = await guild.channels.fetch();
const categoryChannel = channels.filter(
  channel => channel.type === '886241068855734273'
);
```

That `channel.type` won't work though as that snowflake is not one of the `ChannelType`s. You'll either need to use a valid [`ChannelType`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelType) or use `channel.id`.

Comment: There isn't really any reason for `await guild.channels.fetch()`, all channels except for threads are supposed to be cached, unless you manually changed it, so `guild.channels.cache` would work just fine

Answer (score 1):

`Guild#channels` is a `GuildChannelManager`. I also see you are setting your status in a loop, which is a terrible idea, due to it being an API request. Use it outside of it and use `.cache` to get the `Collection` of channels

```js
const categoryChannels = guild.channels.cache.filter(
  (channel) => channel.type === 'GUILD_CATEGORY' // You put an ID, not type, I fixed it for you
);

const statuss = categoryChannels.reduce((acc, channel) => channel.children.size - 2, 0)
client.user.setPresence({
    status: 'online',
    activities: [{ name: `${statuss} Open Tickets ✉️`, type: 'WATCHING' }],
  });
```